# Arabic Numbers Direction Problem in Oracle

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql, oracle

i generate the report from oracle reports application as HTMLCSS .
my issue is the web page has number like "123/587/457/55" 
so how can i show the number from right to left direction for Arabic language . "55/457/587/123"

[image: Report Printed as]

[image: Original Text in Forms Builder]

Answer (score 0):

this reverses the number and writes to console.

```js
const reversedNum = num => parseFloat(num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) * Math.sign(num)



function reverseNum(num) {
 return (
    parseFloat(
      num
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .reverse()
        .join('')
    ) * Math.sign(num)
  )
}

console.log(reversedNum(-543.21))

console.log(reversedNum(23000000))

console.log(reversedNum(543.21))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something that reverses the list of numbers using '/' as a delimiter, you can use...

```
function reverseNumberList(s) {return s.split("/").reverse().join("/")}
```

...which converts...

- "123/587/457/55"

...to...

- "55/457/587/123"